# Migrating existing ETL to NiFi: what processor should I choose?

Tags: apache-nifi

We have existing ETL pipeline, exploring the possibility to migrate the pipeline to NiFi.

Our pipeline contains jobs written in python/scala, and do lots of ingestion/transformation.

What processor NiFi allows me to put python/scala code in it?

Thank you very much.

Comment: you can run any commandline with [ExecuteStreamCommand](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.7.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ExecuteStreamCommand/index.html) or [ExecuteProcess](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.8.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ExecuteProcess/index.html). for python (jython) use [ExecuteScript](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-scripting-nar/1.8.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.script.ExecuteScript/index.html)

Comment: Thank you daggett, as said, this is to migrate existing pipeline, so there are many existing python and scala files, I see there is a properties tab in ExecuteScript configure where there are property of Script File and Script Body, Module Directory, does it mean I can specify my python file there and get it to run in NiFi? Do you have any existing example? Thank you.

Comment: just search `nifi python`. https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/75032/executescript-cookbook-part-1.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Migrating your entire code to NiFi is pretty much missing the point of NiFi.. Seems like what you're looking for is a workflow engine like Apache Oozie or Apache Airflow.

If you really want to migrate to NiFi, try replacing your code logic with NiFi processors. It will look better, and will be easier to maintain.

I do have to warn you, it's not easy if you don't know NiFi well.. You should learn about how to use NiFi first. After you do, you won't regret it :)